# Android WebView Restore State: Pretty Slow

Tags: android, webview, fragment

I have multiple tabs in my activity. Each tab has a fragment with webView.

Desired Output: On tab change, the webView should not load the page every time, but store the state in a Bundle and load the bundle every time on tab change

Actual Output: I am able to achieve the same using webView.savestate(bundle) and webView.restore(bundle). However the transition is not smooth. Loading the page using bundle is slow. I want a lag-free transition.

Please Help me